# When creating component, An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

When i try to generate a component using NG generate component i get this error:
Schematic "appShell" not found in collection "@ionic/angular-toolkit".

or ionic generate component i get this error:
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

I have tried installing @schematics/angular
I am very clueless how to solve this issue, i dont know how to find the schema to change id to $id.

Anybody have a clue?

```
[error] Error: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
at Object.code (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\vocabularies\core\id.js:6:15)
at keywordCode (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:454:13)
at C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:222:17
at CodeGen.code (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:439:13)
at CodeGen.block (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:568:18)
at iterateKeywords (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:219:9)
at groupKeywords (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:208:13)
at C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:192:13
at CodeGen.code (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:439:13)
at CodeGen.block (C:\Users\toni\Desktop\Eventio\Test\Events\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:568:18)


 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
"rxjs": "~7.5.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^14.1.0",
"@angular/localize": "^14.0.6",
"@angular/material": "^14.1.0",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.13",
"@ionic/cordova-builders": "^7.0.0",
"@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^14.0.0",
"ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.6.0",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
"ts-debounce": "^4.0.0",
"validate-npm-package-license": "^3.0.4"
}

 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.5",
"@angular/cli": "^14.0.5",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.0.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.5",
"@angular/language-service": "^14.0.5",
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"cordova-android": "^10.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
"execa": "^6.1.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~4.6.4"
},
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
},
"platforms": [
  "android"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is coming from the line:

```js
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3",
```

Since you have the latest Angular & Ionic packages, you can try to install the latest version of the toolkit with the npm:

```js
npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit@latest --save-dev
```

Also, you should be able to create components with Ionic cli as well.
e.g:

```
ionic generate component xyz
```